# drop down menu to value output

Tags: javascript, html

Apologies, this seems really basic. I'm trying to show the value of a dropdown in an input field. I've been poking it for hours and cant' figure out what I'm doing wrong.

```js
function myFunction(){
         var e = document.getElementById("theDay");
         var dayValue = e.options[e.selectedIndex].value;
           document.getElementById("formValue").value = dayValue;
        }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en">
    <body>
      <form action="" name="theForm">
        <select name="theDay" size="7">
          <option value="0">Monday</option>
          <option value="1">Tuesday</option>
          <option value="2">Wednesday</option>
          <option value="3">Thursday</option>
          <option value="4">Friday</option>
          <option value="5">Saturday</option>
          <option value="6">Sunday</option>
        </select>
      </form>
    <button onclick="myFunction()">Click me</button>
    to show drop down value <input type="text" id="formValue">
 
    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: You don't have id attribute in <select>, add that as <select id ="theDay">

Comment: @NitinDhomse. I could jump out of my window. Thanks I can't believe I didn't see it. wow. I need a rest.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

you missed **id** in your select so replace

```
<select name="theDay" size="7">
```

to

```
<select name="theDay" size="7" id="theDay">
```

```js
function myFunction(){
        var e = document.getElementById("theDay");
        var dayValue = e.options[e.selectedIndex].value;
        document.getElementById("formValue").value = dayValue;
    }
```

```html
<form action="" name="theForm">
    <select name="theDay" size="7" id="theDay">
        <option value="0">Monday</option>
        <option value="1">Tuesday</option>
        <option value="2">Wednesday</option>
        <option value="3">Thursday</option>
        <option value="4">Friday</option>
        <option value="5">Saturday</option>
        <option value="6">Sunday</option>
    </select>
</form>
<button onclick="myFunction()">Click me</button>
to show drop down value <input type="text" id="formValue">
```

Comment: thanks. I saw Nitin's reply and wanted to pull my hair out. time for a walk.

Comment: @userabuserconfuser please accept my answer if it is work . someone will get help from this answer.

Answer (score 0):

Try this in your code **theForm** is name but you call it as id. `e.options[e.selectedIndex].text` get the text and .value to get value

```js
function myFunction() {

  var e = document.getElementById("theDay");
  var day = e.options[e.selectedIndex].text;//value to get value
  document.getElementById("formValue").value = day

}
```

```html
<form action="" name="theForm">
  <select id="theDay" size="7">
      <option value="0">Monday</option>
      <option value="1">Tuesday</option>
      <option value="2">Wednesday</option>
      <option value="3">Thursday</option>
      <option value="4">Friday</option>
      <option value="5">Saturday</option>
      <option value="6">Sunday</option>
    </select>
</form>
<button onclick="myFunction()">Click me</button> to show drop down value <input type="text" id="formValue">
```